# ggplot2 ggplot2 all output is all gray background

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

#1990~2017 RA result
year = c(1990:2017)
result = c(9140,9660,10600,11400,11500,12800,14000,15300,16900,18800,21400,28000,31600,35500,39800,44900,47800,50500,53300,55900,59700,58700,69300,71200,65600,53900,47000,33600)

RA_result <-data.table(year=year, result=result)


ggplot(RA_result)
```

Everytime when I make a plot with ggplot2 all output is all gray background nothing with any plot ONLY just gray color came out.

ggplot2 used to work well in my computer, but somehow it doesn't work as like I mentioned above.

I even did reinstall packages, or even R and R studio, still doesn't work.
is there any problem with in R?

[image: [enter image description here]

Answer (score 2):

The result is exactly as expected. You have passed a data table object to `ggplot` without specifying which variables to plot, or what type of chart you want.

If you want, for example, a column chart:

```
ggplot(RA_result, aes(year, result)) + geom_col()
```

Comment: solved It ! I highly appreciate it ! thank you for your kindness

Comment: You're welcome. Votes and accepted answers are also great ways to thank :)